# Previous approaches for encoding physical affordances

Tags: artificial-intelligence

From Wikipedia, an affordance is:

> a relation between an object or an environment and an organism, that
>   affords the opportunity for that organism to perform an action

Previously what approaches have been used to encode this in an embodied intelligence? In other words, has anyone tried to get a robot to understand the concept of affordances in the real world? If so, how?

A couple examples of tasks that I could imagine to test this concept out:

- A robot encoded with the ability to evaluate which objects are stackable understands the affordance of stacking.
- A robot encoded with the ability to evaluate which object roll well could choose from a set of objects which would roll the best

For background, I'm coming from a cognitive science perspective where the most effective way I've seen for approaching ambiguous input and trying to find underlying patterns is with Vector Symbolic Architectures, but I couldn't think of a way that they could be applied here.

Comment: Encode what?  What do you mean by "encode this in an embodied intelligence"?  What do you mean by "this encoding"?  What do you mean by an encoding?  Can you revise your question to provide additional examples, clarification, elaboration, definitions of terms, etc., so that I can understand what you are asking?

Comment: @D.W. Will do. I'm coming from a cognitive science background so I may have accidentally brought in a lot of jargon accidentally.

Comment: @D.W. I tried to clear up the jargon. Is this an understandable question now?

Comment: That helps.  The first paragraph now makes more sense (though your bullet list is still hard for me to understand).   But I'm not sure whether the question is well-defined -- it's not clear whether there is an experimental procedure to test "understanding".  If I claimed that a particular robot understands the concept of affordances, how would you tell?  If I built a robot that was able to push a swinging door to go through it, would you consider it to understand affordances?  (Even if I programmed it specifically to do that?)  This question seems to get more into philosophical issues.

Comment: There are certainly very old AI projects that built a robot that could move around objects (e.g., children's toys) on a table, including stacking them.  Whether you'd count this as the robot being encoded with an understanding of the affordances of stacking, I don't know; I'm not sure how I'd tell.  That sounds like more a matter of how we, the audience, interprets its behavior rather than anything fundamental about its behavior.